# Custom taxonomy with hierarchical url link structure

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom taxonomy called instrument_categories. It works fine but I want the link structure to be like this:

```
www.example.com/instruments/term/subterm
```

Instead, I get this:

```
www.example.com/instruments/term/
www.example.com/instruments/subterm
```

I've read a dozen posts about this, and I can't find anything wrong with my code:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'create_instrument_taxonomies', 0 );

 function create_instrument_taxonomies()
 {
   // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
   $labels = array(
     'name' => _x( 'Instrument Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
     'singular_name' => _x( 'Instrument Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
     'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Instrument Categories' ),
     'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Instrument Categories' ),
     'all_items' => __( 'All Instrument Categories' ),
     'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Instrument Category' ),
     'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Instrument Category:' ),
     'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Instrument Category' ),
     'update_item' => __( 'Update Instrument Category' ),
     'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Instrument Category' ),
     'new_item_name' => __( 'New Instrument Category Name' ),
   );
       register_taxonomy('instrument_categories',array('sdp_instrument'), array(
         'hierarchical' => true,
         'labels' => $labels,
         'show_ui' => true,
         'query_var' => true,
         'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'instruments', 'hierarchal' => true, 'with_front' => true ),
       ));
 }
```

Am I missing something? I've made sure to refresh the permalinks. Why won't this work?

Comment: If you've figured this out yourself, perhaps with the help of the below article, please add your revised code as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You're really doing it wrong.

Everything you need to know is here : http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: This is really not an answer. That entire blog post does not create an answer for this question, nor was it intended to.

Comment: "It works fine but I want the link structure to be like this:

www.example.com/instruments/term/subterm"

And in the blogpost he explains how to have pretty url with multi params. And if you think about it, you can do whatever you want.

Actually yes, you can't copy/paste the answer, you have to think about it and code. I'm sorry.

Comment: It's fine that you have to think yourself, however this is StackExchange. Here we provide answers to questions, we *do not* say "RTFM". Also, a link may die in the future, which is why they are used for reference, not for answering the entire question.